# Reload in Ext js is not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

What I Need:

- When user clicks on a reload button, then data should be reloded.
- Example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/charts/Pie.html.

The example has helped but I cannot reload data in pie chart. Here is my code:

```
   Ext.onReady(function () {
    store.loadData(generateData());
    var donut = false,
    panel1 = Ext.create('widget.panel', {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    title: 'Semester Trends',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'fit',
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Reload Data',
        handler: function() {
    Ext.Msg.alert("click");
            store.loadData(generateData());
        }
    },
{
 text: 'Save Chart',
        handler: function() {
            Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm Download', 'Would you like to download the chart as an image?', function(choice){
                if(choice == 'yes'){
                    chart.save({
                        type: 'image/png'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },

{
        enableToggle: true,
        pressed: false,
        text: 'Donut',
        toggleHandler: function(btn, pressed) {
            var chart = Ext.getCmp('chartCmp');
            chart.series.first().donut = pressed ? 35 : false;
            chart.refresh();
        }
    }],
    items: {
        xtype: 'chart',
        id: 'chartCmp',
        animate: true,
        store: store,
        shadow: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'right'
        },
        insetPadding: 60,
        theme: 'Base:gradients',

        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            field: 'temperature',
            showInLegend: true,
            donut: donut,
            tips: {
              trackMouse: true,
              width: 140,
              height: 28,
              renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                //calculate percentage.
                var total = 0;
                store.each(function(rec) {
                  total += rec.get('date');
                });
                this.setTitle(storeItem.get('temperature') + ': ' + storeItem.get('date') );
              }
            },
            highlight: {
              segment: {
                margin: 20
              }
            },
           label: {
                field: 'temperature',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            }
        }]
    }
});
});
```

I've also used a sencha example url:  http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/charts/pie/viewer.html but it's not working.

I have to reload the data in charts. My data is loaded into the chart, but it is not able to be reloaded.

example-data.js code :

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {

window.generateData = function(){
    var data = [];

        data.push(
    { temperature: 86, date: new Date(2014, 1, 4, 8) },
    { temperature: 20, date: new Date(2014, 1, 5, 7) },
    { temperature: 75, date: new Date(2014, 1, 1, 11) },
    { temperature: 10, date: new Date(2014, 1, 1, 7) },
    { temperature: 46, date: new Date(2014, 1, 1, 12) }
    );

    return data;

      };




window.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    fields: ['temperature', 'date'],
    data: generateData()
});


  window.loadTask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var chartId = Ext.getStore('myStore');
ChartId.refresh();

try once

Comment: problem in this function store.loadData(generateData()); donut is ok but problem in click on relaod  no data is loaded pls help where i have  done wrong

Comment: please give relevent answer t my code i cann"t understand this solution